# How to i input 2 times for a range instread if pre-entering it

Tags: python, function, input

#i want to count total number of even number in range

## eg 1-11 hascount=5 2,4,5,6,10 thus 5 even number

```
def x(start,end):
    count =0
    for num in range(start,end):
        if num % 2 ==0:
            count=count+1
    return count


print(x(input("  ","   ")))
```

## print(x(1,11))

## how do i input 2 times instead of giving fix range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(x(int(input()), int(input())))
```

Comment: To accept the answer you should press the tick icon under answer's upvote and downvote buttons. More details on the tour page: stackoverflow.com/tour